# Connect to MS Access with PHP not working

Tags: php, database, ms-access

I am trying to connect to a MS Access Database with PHP. It is working perfectly when I am creating a System DSN but how do I make the connection work, when I want to copy and use the PHP files plus Database on a different computer? (Without creating another System DSN on that computer as well)

At the moment I am trying it this way:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("odbc:DRIVER={Microosoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$odbc_name; Uid=$Uid; Pwd=$Pwd;");
```

And I am getting this error:

> Warning: odbc_connect() expects at least 3 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\PartB\db_connection.php on line 14

The file is correctly found with this line of code:

```
$odbc_name = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "PartB\db.mdb";
```

So where is my problem? Why is this way not working, but System DSN is? Any ideas?

Comment: The error tells you that [`odbc_connect`](http://php.net/odbc_connect) needs three parameters, a separate $user and $password argument namely. And how is the database interface supposed to connect to a remote installations access database without configuring the ODBC link?

Comment: But I do have a $user and $password argument, but they are not accepted somehow. Does it matter, that they have null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a answer to this myself.

```
$conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=$odbc_name";
```

The above code makes the connection work without System DSN.

Now I just need to reconfigure my query statements and all good.